# Initiate field value before adding new feature

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, actions

I have two layers:

- Chambre(obj_id)
- Ouvrage(obj_id, fk_chambre)

The attribute Ouvrage.fk_chambre is referencing the attribute Chambre.obj_id.

I'm trying to create an action on the Chambre layer that permit to add a feature in the Ouvrage layer and directly add the obj_id of the chambre feature in the new created Ouvrage feature.

Here is my actual code:

```
ouvrage_lyr = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayer('od_ouvrage20171121140457844')
chambre_lyr = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayer('od_chambre20171121140457773')

feature = chambre_lyr.getFeatures( QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression( 'obj_id = \'{}\''.format( '[% "obj_id" %]' ) ) ).next()

#Get the value of the clicked feature obj_id
fk_chambre = feature["obj_id"]

#create the new feature in the ouvrage layer
ouvrage_lyr.startEditing()
qgis.utils.iface.setActiveLayer(ouvrage_lyr)
qgis.utils.iface.actionAddFeature().trigger()
```

My question: How can I automatically fill the attribute Ouvrage.fk_chambre with the fk_chambre variable?

Comment: Adding features to the Ouvrage layer is this being done by code, a plugin, or within the normal editing process in QGIS?

Comment: It should be done by the code. The idea is to click on the Chambre element and then be able to digitize a new Ouvrage feature whit the fk_chambre attribute directly fill. (The obj_id of the ouvrage feature is incremented by the database)